# Calcium-containing acidic solution

Tags: solutions, ph, precipitation

I want to prepare an acidic solution containing Ca ions. I thought about dissolving calcium sulphate, acetate or phosphate in $\pu{2 M}$ $\ce{H2SO4}$ or $\ce{H3PO4}$ solutions, but it seems that $\ce{Ca}$ cations react with sulphate anions.

Is it true? And is there any way to make a $\ce{Ca}$-containing acidic solution?

(I forgot to say I need $\ce{Cl}$  & $\ce{F}$  free solution...)

Comment: You could dissolve calcium chloride in water and add a small amount of HCl.

Comment: Then go for nitrate. And if you don't like it for some reason, there are quite a few more acids out there.

Comment: The best way to produce a calcium containing acidic solution is using calcium nitrate in HNO3 containing acidic solution. And please avoid sulfate or phosphate ions, which produce precipitates with calcium ions. Why do you want to avoid chloride ions ?

Comment: no chloride allowed

Answer (score 1):

Probably your most flexible option is to make a buffer solution of a weak acid with its calcium salt. For instance, calcium acetate plus acetic acid with equal molarities of acetate ion and acetic acid will have a pH of about 4.8. If you want a more strongly acidic solution, you can use sulfamic acid ($pK_a\approx 1$) as the acid. Calcium sulfamate, unlike calcium sulfate, is readily soluble in water. Sulfamic acid is in fact used commercially in lime-scale cleaners.

Answer (score 0):

If nitric acid is not suitable sulfamic as mentioned or possibly methanesulfonic or benzenesulfonic acids supposedly have soluble calcium salts and should be strong enough. A good idea would be to start with CaCO3, chalk, and dissolving it. then there would be only the acid anion present after the CO2 is evolved.